# Use chrome with Selenium 2.0 with C#

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have a problem with the ChromeDriver.exe When I run the test, a Google Chrome Window is open but then an error from the chromedriver console shows up. It says something like:

> [0405/175241: WARNING:scoped_temp_dir.cc<15>] Could not delete temp
>   dir in dtor.

Can anybody help me?....I'm Using C# by the way.

I wanned to upload an image but I couldn't because I'm a new user...

-JM

Comment: Could we know the version of Selenium and Chrome. Does the test run on other browsers like Firefox. Have you tried with the latest stable version of Chrome and the ChromeDriver (downloadable from the chromium.googlecode.com site).

Comment: I'm using Selenium IDE 1.7.2 (with C# WebDriver); Google Chrome 18.0.1025.142 m. The test run perfect in Firefox and Internet Explorer. I have the  ChromeDriver that I got from : http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list (The 19.0)

Comment: I got it resolved now...I used the version 18.0 of the Driver ...

Comment: If anybody have the same question you have to do this:

using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

driver = new ChromeDriver();
baseURL = "http://google.com.co";
verificationErrors = new StringBuilder();

And then...you can do any test...whatever you want. But the ChromeDriver.exe must be saved in the Debug folder of your project (I'm using Visual Studio with C# and NUnit). Just next with .DLL of your test. That's all

Answer (score 1):

**Selenium WebDriver C# in ChromeDriver:**

**Prerequisite:** Install Visual Studio (mine is VS 2017), Google Chrome browser

Steps to follow:

1. Open VS 2017 and create solution/project
2. Write a test using C# code as below:

   IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
   driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("Your Test URL");

Now install "Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver" by following steps:

1. Right click on Project -> Manage NuGet Packages...
2. Click Browse at the top and search for ChromeDriver
3. Select "Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver" and install it
4. Execute/Run your test

Comment: It should be the same for VS 2015

Answer (score 0):

Instead of moving your chromedriver.exe, when creating a new instance of a ChromeDriver you may put the exe's file path as a parameter. This is the same as for IE.
For example: driver = new ChromeDriver("C:\ChromeDriverFolder"); will look for the cromedriver.exe in a folder on the C drive called 'ChromeDriverFolder'.